# Android System's use of Binder Tokens

Tags: android, android-binder

I am reading about use of Binder tokens inside Android System at [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/07/binders-window-tokens.html) blog post. I saw the example related to wakelocks where the token is used to identify subsequent requests from same application.

I want to ask why in the Android system the `UID` of the calling application is not enough to track subsequent requests from the application ? Is there any need Binder tokens fulfill that UID cannot in terms of identifying an application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Binder token does not identify an application in the way that the `uid` does. A token is a capability or ticket, which means that *possession* is what counts. In other words, with a binder token, it doesn't matter *who* or *what* you are, but only whether you possess the token. This last part is key: in the Android Framework, there are many objects that need to be differentiated for security reasons, but they either all have the same `uid` (e.g., objects in the `system_server` process space) and/or the `uid` doesn't identify the true subject (e.g., code running on the local side of Binder RPC).

This difference with respect to `uid` enables functionality that wouldn't be easily achievable, or even possible with `uid`. A good example is in the [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/07/binders-window-tokens.html) you referenced:

> Applications can ask the `InputMethodManager` to hide the soft keyboard
>   by calling the `hideSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder windowToken, int flags)`
>   method, but must provide a window token as part of the request. If the
>   token doesn't match the window token belonging to the window currently
>   accepting input, the `InputMethodManager` will reject the request. This
>   makes it impossible for malicious applications to force-close a soft
>   keyboard opened by another application.

The main reason for using tokens here is that a window object isn't something that has a `uid`. Sure, it is part of some process somewhere that has a `uid`, but whatever that `uid` is, it's not the `uid` of the application trying to hide the soft keyboard. Thus, the only way ensure that the requester own the window currently accepting input is to force the application to supply the token it was given by `WindowManager` when the window was first created.